# Jump through blocks of lines in a file based on a conditional

Tags: perl, file

I have a .bedGraph file which looks like this:

```
chr     start   end     score
chr1    3000305 3000306 0.006
chr1    3000306 3000307 0.01
chr1    3000307 3000308 0.014
chr1    3000308 3000309 0.017
chr1    3000309 3000310 0.019
chr1    3000310 3000313 0.021
chr1    3000313 3000314 0.029
chr1    3000314 3000315 0.027
chr1    3000315 3000316 0.02
chr1    3000316 3000317 0.011
```

I have to write a script which will traverse through this file and look for score >0.02, grab the ***start*** value for that score, and continue searching until it reaches a score <0.02 at which point it should grab the previous ***end*** position. So in this case the program should traverse from the beginning of the file, identify the first score>0.02, grab the **start position=3000310** for that score and continue searching until the score falls below 0.02 at which it should grab the previous **end position=3000316**. After this, it should continue searching the file for such blocks and grab the start and end positions of **blocks** containing score>0.02. Again, it should *not grab all the starts and ends of a block containing a score>0.02* but *only the first start and last end of such a block*.

I have written part of the code but don't know how to proceed further:

```
open BEDGRAPH, $ARGV[0] or die print $!;

my $thresh=0.5;
my $j=1;
my $i=1;
my @arr = <BEDGRAPH>;
my @tmp;
for $i (0 .. $#arr)
{
my ($chr, $start, $end, $score) = split('\s',$arr[$i]);
if($score>=$thresh)
{
    push(@tmp,$chr);
    push(@tmp,$start);
    $j=$i+1;
    my ($chr1, $start1, $end1, $score1) = split('\s',$arr[$j]);
    while($score1>=$thresh)
    {
        $j=$j+1;
    }
    my ($chr2, $start2, $end2, $score2) = split('\s',$arr[$j-1]);
    push(@tmp,$end2);
    $i=$j+1;
    print @tmp;
}
elsif($score>=$thresh)
{
        $i=$i+1;
}
}

close(BEDGRAPH);
```

Here I am trying to push the required start & end positions in @tmp and print it.

Comment: What's the output?  If your program is just "grabbing" data, then what's the point?  Do you want to output everything you "grab"?

Comment: The output is a file with each line containing a start and end position that the program grabs each time it encounters such a block of scores>0.02.

Comment: Your description says `> 0.02` but your code says `> 0.5`. You should store that value in a variable anyway.

Comment: I have updated my code, I actually have to find it for score>0.5 but I could only paste a subset of my file here so had to change the score.

Comment: When making such a substantial edit to a question that you already marked as answered, you should really open a new question for the new, specific issue you're facing. I updated my answer for your new code.

Comment: I did make a new question, but one of the users marked it as duplicated, and he asked me to edit this question. When I told him that I am making a different change and that this question has already been answered, he told me you should mark it as "unanswered" so that people get your question in the new questions' list.

Comment: The new question you asked was not a duplicate, but it was hard to tell because large parts were word-for-word identical. Just because one user thinks your post is a dupe does not mean the community will agree. See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96560/significantly-edit-existing-question-or-ask-a-new-question-after-answer-accepte) on meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to make changes to your program as noted by ThisSuitisBlackNot. I thought I'd post a possible solution.

**Update:** If the chr name can change, this program may not work and need to be adjusted.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($prev_chr, $prev_start, $prev_end);
my $thresh = .02;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($chr, $start, $end, $score) = split;

    if ($score >= $thresh) {
        $prev_chr   //= $chr;
        $prev_start //= $start;
        $prev_end = $end;
    }
    else {
        if ($prev_chr) {
            print "$prev_chr $prev_start $prev_end\n";
            ($prev_chr, $prev_start, $prev_end) = (undef) x 3;
        }
    }
}
print "$prev_chr $prev_start $prev_end\n" if $prev_chr;

__DATA__
chr1    3000305 3000306 0.006
chr1    3000306 3000307 0.01
chr1    3000307 3000308 0.014
chr1    3000308 3000309 0.017
chr1    3000309 3000310 0.019
chr1    3000310 3000313 0.021
chr1    3000313 3000314 0.029
chr1    3000314 3000315 0.027
chr1    3000315 3000316 0.02
chr1    3000316 3000317 0.011
```

Comment: I am clueless about what are you trying to do here

Comment: @user2703967 Output is `chr1 3000310 3000316`, which is the result you said you wanted. The statement, for example, `$prev_chr   //= $chr;` is equivalent to `$prev_chr = $chr unless defined $prev_chr;`.

Comment: Pardon me, I am not that good at Perl. You can see how much difference there is between your code & mine. I will try to understand what this code does and implement into mine, although I would be honest to say that have never seen terms like (undef)*3 and so on. Thanks.

Comment: `($prev_chr, $prev_start, $prev_end) = (undef) x 3;' sets the three variables to `undef'. The `(undef) x 3` creates a list of three values == undef and assigns them to the 3 variables on the left side. They remain undefined until the score is >= to the threshold and then assigns to them (if their previous value is undefined).

Comment: I made 1 edit to the program, undefining the previous values after printing out the desired record.

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions to get you started.

First, why loop through your file twice? You do it once when you read it into an array and again when you process the array. Why not just do the processing as your read the file line by line?

```
# Use a lexical filehandle and test `open` for failure
my $file = $ARGV[0];
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Failed to open file '$file': $!";

while (<$fh>) {
    my ($chr, $start, $end, $score) = split;
...
```

Note that instead of referring to the columns with array indexes, I'm using meaningful variable names.

Also, avoid magic numbers like the plague and put your threshold in a variable. This way if it does change from 0.02 to 0.5, you only have to update it in one place in your code. Variable names also tend to be more meaningful than magic numbers to the people reading your code.

```
my $threshold = 0.02;
```

There are a few pieces of information you need to keep track of as you read through your file.

1. Are you inside a block (i.e. a section where the scores are greater than your threshold)?
2. If you are inside a block, what is the value of `start` at the beginning of the block?
3. If you are inside a block, What is the value of `end` from the previous line? You need this because you don't find out you've left a block until the following line.

If you think about how you can get these pieces of information, you should be able to figure out the rest.

---

**EDIT:** You *completely* changed your code with your latest edit. This should really be a new question.

Immediate issues with your updated code:

```
open BEDGRAPH, $ARGV[0] or die print $!;
```

Use lexical filehandles (`open my $fh`) instead of typeglobs (`open FILE`), which are global in scope.

```
my @arr = <BEDGRAPH>;
```

You mentioned in the comments that you're working with really large files, and yet you're reading them into memory with `@array = <$fh>`. You should really use `while (<$fh>) ...`

```
while($score1>=$thresh)
{
    $j=$j+1;
}
```

And finally, you never change the values of `$score` or `$thresh` in the body of your loop, so it runs forever.

Comment: You could drop the delimiter from `split` with the same result (it'll use the default `" "` as in the question).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have been already trying to think of a way to enter the block and do something like **next until** it reaches a score below the threshold. But I am still stuck. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: @user2703967 Did you try `next if $score <= $threshold`? You would of course only want to run that test if you were already inside a block.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I have figured out this problem in R, I will try to implement the same in Perl too. Thanks!

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Is there a way to loop through a file in perl using a for loop where a variable i iterates and reads the next line?

Comment: @user2703967 When you use a `for` loop, the entire list you're iterating through is in memory. To do this with a file requires reading the entire file into memory, which can be done with `my @array = <$fh>;`. This is fine if your file is small, but can eat up a significant chunk of RAM with large files. However, nothing says you can't use a counter with a `while` loop: `my $line = 1; while (<$fh>) { do something; $line++; }`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thanks, I have added my implementation in R above. So based on this logic, I will have to have a i and j variable to traverse through parts of my file. I will try what you have suggested. I am hesitant to use R because my files are really large, and I think perl will handle it better.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38195/discussion-between-user2703967-and-thissuitisblacknot)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I don't understand. How will I loop through the file if I use while(<$fh>) instead of for $i...; Also, what is the change with while($score1>=$thresh){}? I have the same thing in my code.

Comment: Am I not changing the value of $score each time it reads the next line in the for loop -> my ($chr, $start, $end, $score) = split('\s',$arr[$i]);

Comment: @user2703967 When `$score` is greater than `$thresh` and you enter the `while` loop, what happens? Say `$score` is 0.021 and `$j` is some number. In the first iteration, you increment `$j` by one. `$score` is still 0.021, so you go through the loop again. Increment `$j` again. `$score` is *still* 0.021, so go through the loop again. And so on, forever.

Comment: But it is not even going past the if statement! After the if statement and before the while loop, if I try to print something, it doesn't happen.

Comment: @user2703967 You need to do some basic troubleshooting here. If you're not entering the `if` statement, check the value of `$score` you get from your first `split` and make sure it is really greater than your threshold.

Comment: Which I did. I printed the $score before the if statement, infact I printed the entire line before the if statement, I tried to print the $score & $thresh inside the if statement and even print $i and $j. I have tried printing every variable in every loop, before and after. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh, '<', 'bedgraph.txt' or die "cant open bedgraph.txt $!";

my $thresh = 0.02;

my @start_pos;
my @end_pos;
my $previous_end;

my $header = <$fh>;

ABOVE:
while (<$fh>){
    my ($chr, $start, $end, $score) = split;
    if ($score > $thresh){
        push @start_pos, $start;
        $previous_end = $end;
        BELOW:
        while (<$fh>){ 
            my ($chr, $start, $end, $score) = split;
            if ($score < $thresh){
                push @end_pos, $previous;
                next ABOVE;  
            }
            $previous = $end;        
        }      
    }
}    

close $fh;

print "Start positions found: @start_pos\n";
print "End positions found: @end_pos\n";

#Start positions found: 3000310
#End positions found: 3000316
```

**Brief Explanation:**

- **ABOVE loop:** scan file looking for a score greater than treshold. *When/if* a value is found it stores the value from the *start* column of the *current line* in the array **@start_pos** . and then it passes control to the loop indentified by BELOW. *let's say the value was found on line number six*.
- **BELOW loop:** start scanning file at line *number seven* looking for values *below* the threshold. *When/if* a value is found it store the value from the *end* column of the *previous line* in the array **@end_pos** . and then it passes control to the loop indentified by ABOVE. *let's say the value was found on line number ten*.
- **ABOVE loop:** start scanning the file at *line eleven* and the proccess repeat itself until  every line of the file has been read.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $startFound = 0;
my $priorEnd;

while (<>) {
    $. > 1 or next;    # Get past the header
    my ( undef, $start, $end, $score ) = split;

    if ( $score > .02 and !$startFound ) {
        $startFound = 1;
        print "Start: $start\n";
    }

    if ( $score < .02 and $startFound ) {
        $startFound = 0;
        print "End  : $priorEnd\n";
    }

    $priorEnd = $end;
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

This script sets a flag (`$startFound`) to signal the beginning of a block, and then checks for a score below .02 and that flag to find that block's end.  The var `$priorEnd` just holds that last 'end' value, for the start/end pair.

Hope this helps!